# Which is better to use in Android, a 1px*1px .png image or a drawable .xml with a solid rectangle?

Tags: android, performance, resources, drawable

Which is better to use in Android and why?

- Load a .png file that is 1x1 and has, obviously, one pixel of one color (ie #000)
- Use an .xml drawable that contains a solid rectangle of the same solid color (#000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is better to use in Android and why?

Use an .xml drawable that contains a solid rectangle of the same solid color (#000).

**Why?** Because that's the point of the XML layouts, is to enable developers to quickly make changes to visuals (in this case colors) without having to open image-editing software.

If you were to *really* only load a 1x1 PNG then some could argue the PNG loading is faster, but in reality, this is never going to happen. The point here is that it will be stretched or manipulated in some way, or set to tile as a background and this will eventually be slower than defining a background color or shape in Android XML Layout.

Comment: Moreover, Android XMLs are compiled to be more dense. PNGs are already compressed.  XMLs will use less storage.

Answer (score 1):

i think that png is better, because is native and take less time to load.xml is needed parser, so is a little low than png. i think, but i never tried it.

**UPDATE**
i make a files with these specifications, and the results are those:

png 1x1 black dot [119 bytes]
xml rectangle blac [261 bytes]
**UPDATE 2**

[Performance wise, what is typically better, using an image or a xml created shape as a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006637/performance-wise-what-is-typically-better-using-an-image-or-a-xml-created-shape)

Comment: I had downvoted your answer which was along the lines of "I think but who knows". Now that you added more information I'm undoing. I also don't think your test is very helpful, the kb size of the files isn't indicative at all of which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

For a single color, use a color resource. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color This will be more performant than a 1x1 stretched image or an xml drawable.

As general performance guidelines, solid colors are the cheapest, followed by unstretched bitmaps, followed by 9-patches and stretched bitmaps. Shape drawables are usually the most expensive at runtime.